How do I reload the browser in React Testing Library?
In a React app, I would like to confirm that edits are saved after pressing the "save" button, and will be reloaded when refreshing the screen. To make sure I am testing the right thing, I would like to first test that edits are not saved when not pressing the "save" button. So I would like a test that looks something like this:
render(myUI());

expect(await screen.findByLabelText('Name')).toHaveValue('');

await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('Name'), 'Simon');

expect(await screen.findByLabelText('Name')).toHaveValue('Simon');

// HERE, RELOAD THE SCREEN

expect(await screen.findByLabelText('Name')).toHaveValue('');


I can't figure out what to write to do "reload" the screen. I have tried various things like the rerender. But the 'Simon' value is always kept. Is there a good way to do this – basically simulating that the user performs a reload of the page?
